# program to add one to each digit of a number

Tags: c

As new to competitive programming, I was solving this practice question. The goal is to write a program to display numbers whose digits are 1 greater than the corresponding digits of the entered number. So if the number input is 12345 then the output number should be 23456. I have figured out how to separate each number and add them, but I was unable able to take a **number of test cases in the following program.**

The question is as follows

**Input**

First line of input will contain a number N = number of test cases. Next N lines will contain number n as test case where 1<=n<=99999.

**Output**

For each input case, add one to each digit of n, and print the new number.

As a beginner in competitive programming would be helpful if you give some tips to optimize the code.

here is the code that I have written.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n, t, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    int a[t];
    for (int j = 0; j < t; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &n);
            a[i] = n;

            if (t == 1) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 1;
                }
            }
            else if (t == 2) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 10;
                }
                else if (i == 1) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 1;
                }
            }
            else if (t == 3) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 100;
                }
                else if (i == 1) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 10;
                }
                else if (i == 2) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 1;
                }
            }
            else if (t == 4) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 1000;
                }
                else if (i == 1) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 100;
                }
                else if (i == 2) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 10;
                }
                else if (i == 3) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 1;
                }
            }
            else if (t == 5) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 10000;
                }
                else if (i == 1) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 1000;
                }
                else if (i == 2) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 100;
                }
                else if (i == 3) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 10;
                }
                else if (i == 4) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 1;
                }
            }
            else if (t == 6) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 100000;
                }
                else if (i == 1) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 10000;
                }
                else if (i == 2) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 1000;
                }
                else if (i == 3) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 100;
                }
                else if (i == 4) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 10;
                }
                else if (i == 4) {
                    a[i] = (a[i] + 1) * 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: There's no way that's java code and it looks a lot more like C than C++ so I removed the extra tags.

Comment: Use a string data type.  It's trivial to add one to a character to go to the next one.  You just need to decide how to handle adding one to a `'9'`

Comment: Stack overflow is primarily for fixing problems with code. When you have code that works and you think it can work better, consider asking at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). I linked to the Asking help pages because that's the best place for you to start.

Comment: Consider using `switch` conditional whenever you need to compare a variable (for example an int) with several constant values.

Comment: I fixed your indentation for you so that your code is actually readable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is should be posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mobashshir Iqbal What is the result number for the number 99999?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reworked on the code from beginning and I've made a solution for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num, sum, remainder, check; // check used as a boolean expression
    sum = check = 0;

    printf("Enter the sequence: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while (num > 0)
    {
        remainder = num % 10; // each time num is reduced

        if (remainder != 9)
        {
            if (check == 0)
                sum = (10 * sum) + (remainder + 1);
            else
            {
                sum = (10 * sum) + (remainder + 2);
                check = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sum = (10 * sum) + 0;
            check = 1;
        }
        num /= 10; // will divide and execute in each iteration until it's true
    }

    num = sum; // final number will be equal to the sum
    sum = 0;

    // Summing up the results
    while (num > 0)
    {
        remainder = num % 10;
        sum = (10 * sum) + remainder;
        num /= 10;
    }

    printf("Result: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

> **Test Output**

```
Enter the sequence: 23456
Result: 34567
```

It's just all about the sum & remainder. Hope it helps you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int num,i=1,j;
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int numo=scan.nextInt();num=numo;
    for(;numo>0;numo=numo/10,i=i*10)
    {
      num=num+i;
      if(numo%10==9)  
      num=num-i*10;  
    } 
  System.out.println(num);
  }
}
```

Comment: it will ignore the carry digit.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution uses the basic remainder and reverse approach:

```
int addOne(int n)
{
    int rem, ans=0, p=1 ;
    while(n>0)
    {
        rem = n%10;
        (rem == 9)?rem = 0:rem+=1;
        ans+=p*rem;
        p*=10;n/=10;
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
   
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   cout<<addOne(n);
   return 0;
}
```